# GCloud remote access (interface or terminal)

Tags: gcloud

I utilize GCloud for hosting a HTTP server. I would like to access the server files along the request process. I am aware of app engine on Linux, and its command `logs`, but the verbose response does not provide, for example, the content of respective server folder. I would be glad if some of you know about how to access such information.

I thank in advance.
Best regards,
Bruno Peixoto

Comment: How to setup this flex configuration which you mention?

Comment: Use env : flex in app.yaml

Comment: @Aadeshkale those comments seem to be the right answer. Can you post it as an actual answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access server files of App Engine in Standard environment, but you can in the Flex one. Use env: flex in [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml)